# extension of holomorphic functions on complex manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

$M$ is a compact complex manifold of complex dimension $n$, and $D$ is a simple smooth divisor on $M$. My question is that whether a holomorphic function on $M-D$ can be extended to $M$. If not, what restriction can be given such that the extension holds?

Comment: A holomorphic function on a compact complex manifold is constant, so the only functions on $M\setminus D$ which can extend are the constant ones...

Comment: Yes, I know this. But my question now is that if I have a function that is holomorphic on $M\setminus D$, what property can be added to $D$ or $M$ such that this function can be extended, and before extension I do not know other property of this function.